# Azure DevOps API- How to create a repository?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm developing a internal app that creates the skeleton of a solution according to internal guidelines.

As a improvement, I would like to enable the user to automatically have the solution "formalized" on our DevOps, where he would clone and start coding right away, instead of the current download as ZIP.

In order to do that, i started looking at the azure devops docs, but could not figure out a way to create a repository via API...

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact thing, were you able to figure this out?
The answers below show how you can create a new repo, but how do you upload the entire solution to this new repo?

Comment: @MattF I didn't finished this implementation... project was shutdown

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample of code we use in a PowerShell script to create repos

```
$repoBody = @{
    name = "YourRepoName"
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-WebRequest -method Post -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $encodedPat"} -body $repoBody -Uri $projUrl -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the [Repositories - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Rest API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.0
```

Body:

```
{
  "name": "NewRepository",
  "project": {
    "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the API call you are looking for:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.0
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you have the AZ modules loaded in powershell, you can simply execute

```
    az repos create --name "MyNewRepoName" --org "https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/" --project "ProjectNameToCreateRepoIn"
```

To install AZ modules in powershell use command

```
    Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

With AZ modules installed execute this before creating repo

```
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "YourSubscriptionID
```